# Word VBA macro to add a period at the end of list items within a selected range

Tags: vba, ms-word

So i highlight a numbered list or bullet point, then i run the macro. It should check each item of the numbered list if it ends with period "." . If it doesn't end with a period, ignore

```
Sub AddPeriodonList()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lastChar As String
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Selection.Range

    For Each para In selectedRange.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.ListFormat.listType <> wdListNoNumbering Then
            ' Get the last visible character of the list item (excluding paragraph marker).
            lastChar = Right(para.Range.Text, 1)
            ' Remove the paragraph marker from the last character
            If lastChar = vbCr Then
                lastChar = Right(para.Range.Text, 2)
            End If
            Debug.Print lastChar ' (print on immediate window for debugging)
            ' Checking if the last character is not a period "."
            If lastChar <> "." Then
                ' Add a period at the end of the list item on the same line.
                para.Range.Characters(para.Range.Characters.count - 2).InsertAfter "."
            End If
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

So the problem is `lastChar`  actually returns the correct character, which is the last character of each item on the numbered list, So i am now trying to check that if it is period or not but seems not to work, as the macro adds period to every item on the list every time its being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Right(para.Range.Text, 2)`  returns the last two characters of a string.  Please use `Mid` to get a characters.

```vb
Sub AddPeriodonList()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lastChar As String, sTxt As String
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Selection.Range

    For Each para In selectedRange.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListNoNumbering Then
            sTxt = para.Range.Text
            ' Get the last visible character of the list item (excluding paragraph marker).
            lastChar = Right(sTxt, 1)
            ' Remove the paragraph marker from the last character
            If lastChar = vbCr Then
                lastChar = Mid(sTxt, Len(sTxt) - 1, 1)
            End If
            Debug.Print lastChar ' (print on immediate window for debugging)
            ' Checking if the last character is not a period "."
            If lastChar <> "." Then
                ' Add a period at the end of the list item on the same line.
                para.Range.Characters(para.Range.Characters.Count - 1).InsertAfter "."
            End If
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @taller_ExcelHome this worked absolutely well.